# Java: Reversing a number in sequence

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program to enter a sequence of numbers ending in 0, which calculates and displays the number of digits read in reverse.
Example: If the sequence consists of digits: 5,3,8,2,0 Then the program will have to display the number 2835
but somehow I'm stuck in a loop and can't seem to figure it out as you can see below

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int note;
int reversed = 0;

do {
    System.out.println("Donnez un nombre plus grand que 0 ou 0 pour terminer");
    note = sc.nextInt();
    int digits = note % 10;
    reversed = reversed * 10 + digits;
    note = note / 10;
}
while (note == 0);
{
    System.out.println("Les numeros a l'envers est " + reversed)
}
```

Comment: why do you prompt and accept a new number each iteration of your loop?

Comment: Because in the question it said I have to enter a sequence where the output asks a new number each time then reverses it.

Comment: Then it doesn't make any sense to divide your input with 10, when both values are integer and the division will yield 0 for all your one-digit numbers and you don't actual care about the division result. Also, using `note == 0` in your `while` loop makes no sense at all either. You want it to loop ___until___ note is 0, not ___as long as___ it is 0.

Comment: formatted code so indentation was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you want to take a number and reverse it and again take a nunber and reverse it and so on. Then you need to use a for() loop before your conditions.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0;;i++){
        System.out.println("Donnez un nombre plus grand que 0 ou 0 pour terminer");
        int note = sc.nextInt();
        int reversed = 0;

        do {
            int digits = note % 10;
            reversed = reversed * 10 + digits;
            note = note/10;
        }
        while (note > 0); {
            System.out.println("Les numeros a l'envers est " + reversed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you process `note` in your loop, you are expecting a single input number (having multiple digits):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int reversed = 0;

System.out.println("Donnez un nombre plus grand que 0 ou 0 pour terminer");
int note = sc.nextInt();
do {
  int digits = note % 10;
  reversed = reversed * 10 + digits;
  note = note/10;
} while (note > 0); 
System.out.println("Les numeros a l'envers est " + reversed)
```

Also note that the loop's condition should be `note > 0`, since you want to leave the loop when `note` becomes `0`.

Comment: I've tried your correction and it will only let me input one single number before the program stops

Comment: @QuangCao that's the point. Your loop reverses a single input number, so there's no point in reading a new input number in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The concise implementation idea can be expressed in Kotlin

```
   val input = with(Scanner(System.`in`)) {
        generateSequence { nextInt() }
                .takeWhile { it > 0 }
                .toList()
    }
    println(input.reversed())
```

But we cannot stop the sequence generation in Java8 yet (but *they say*, we have smth like `takeWhile` in Java 9). So the most readable solution in Java is

```java
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true){
            int next = scanner.nextInt();
            if(next == 0){
                break;
            }
            input.add(next);
        }
        Collections.reverse(input);
```

and then

```java
String source = input.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
long result = Long.parseLong(source));
```